# Identifying dependent/independent events - electricity supply and a lightbulb

Tags: probability, independence

Let's say there's a lightbulb with probability 0.9 that it will work when provided electricity. Let's also say that the power station providing power to the lightbulb is flaky and the probability of it generating electricity is 0.8. The lightbulb cannot operate without the power station.

Is the event of the lightbulb operating dependent on the event that the power station is providing electricity? What is the probability that both power station and lightbulb are working?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(B)\times\Pr(A\mid B)$.  You are told $\Pr(\text{power station works}) = 0.8$ and you are told other pieces of information in the problem.

Comment: Just to clear the record this isn't homework, I'm just starting with probability as an adult and I'm trying to develop an intuition for when events are dependent. The examples I've read represent the second probability being reduced by the first with some physical characteristic, like coloured balls in a bag or a deck of cards. What I'm struggling with is how to determine what $P(A | B)$ means when (if?) the events are already expressed as probabilities.

Comment: I don't understand what specifically you are having difficulty with here.  You could say there are two or three events at play here (*maybe you want to have the event that the bulb is defective defined separately than the event that the bulb is actively lit up*).  The probability is $0.9\times 0.8$.  The lightbulb being lit or not being lit is dependent on whether or not you provide power to it.  If no power, then no light.  If power, then there is a chance for light.

Comment: @JMoravitz the probability you describe is the formula for independent events, isn't it? I find it difficult to understand how the formula for the probability of two lightbulbs being lit $P(A) \cdot P(B)$ is the same as the scenario described above where a lightbulb cannot be lit without being provided power, and is dependent upon it.

Comment: Or is it just as simple as a logical AND of the two events, regardless of one event only being able to occur when the other has?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion caused!

Comment: The probability $0.9$ here is not $\Pr(A)$ but rather $\Pr(A\mid B)$ where $A$ is the event that the bulb is lit.  $\Pr(A\mid B^c)=0$, and $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B^c)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\mid B^c)\Pr(B^c)= 0.9\times 0.8 + 0\times 0.2 = 0.9\times 0.8$.  In general it is false that $\Pr(A\cap B)= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.  That is true if and only if the events are independent.  On the other hand $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)$ is always true regardless

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @JMoravitz. I think I get it now, much appreciated!

Comment: @JMoravitz is that the law of total probability?

Comment: Part of what I said is what some people refer to as the law of total probability, yes.  It all follows from definitions however and didn't need to be named anything.